# How does cascade:'all-delete-orphan' work?

Tags: mongodb, grails, cascade, cascading-deletes

I am working with grails application with mongodb in the backend. I have two domain classes:

```
class User {
    String login
    String password
    static hasMany = [
        addWebsites: Website
    ]
    static mapping = {  addWebsites cascade:'all-delete-orphan'  }
}
```

and other domain class as:

```
class Website{
    String website
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    static constraints = {
        website( url:true, unique: ['user'])
    }
}
```

I tried deleting a user directly from mongodb and expected the realted websites to be deleted as well, but it didn't. I was wondering if I directly delete a user from the mongodb database, should it also delete the related websites or this cascade delete works only when we delete users via grails app?

Comment: That only works from within Grails via your Domain class.

Comment: So I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascading as you have here only works within Grails and GORM via your Domain classes. It does not implement any database level triggers or constraints.